# Expose DLL thru Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll

Hello i'm working on a personal project. It is a web/text based game.

I'm planning on making my classes into DLL and exposing their methods in Web Service.

I'm pretty sure this is possible. But can't find a good tutorial on how to start with this.

So far, i know how to make DLL, I know how to create Web Service. But can anyone help me with exposing my DLL thru Web Service?

Comment: Yeah. Down voting this is rediculous. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the web service (e.g. using C#)
2. Add references to your .dll (e.g. using PInvoke)
3. Voila.  You've just "exposed your .dll through a web service".

Here's a link describing how to call unmanaged code in a .dll from C#.  You can find many other, similar references on the web.  The mechanism is the same, regardless if the C# code is for a Windows form, a console app ... or a web service:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/02/780637.aspx

Comment: what is your point of view about (web app -> web service -> dll) vs (web app -> wcf -> dll) what do you suggest that i should use? or do you have better methods you can propose? i appreciate your help thank you

Comment: paulsm4, why do you assume that Philip wants to call *unmanaged* dlls? The entire question seems like someone's trying to learn how to separate things into libraries and service interfaces using... well, managed code.

Comment: Good point.  @Philip Badilla - you can just as easily reference *managed* .dll's in your web service project.  Regarding web service vs. WCF - Web services are easier to write, and you can use Web services on other (non-Microsoft) platforms.  I'd definitely learn web services before you tackle WCF.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 i do know how to make web services the things is im just having trouble with referencing a DLL.. i think its not just as simple as Add Reference in the IDE because my DLL is not showing in intellisense. can you please help me with that?